# HTTP requests to OTLP endpoint /v1/logs not working

Tags: fluent-bit, open-telemetry-collector

I am trying to interface fluent-bit with an otel collector. Following is the configuration file for fluent bit

```
    ##################### Debugging #######################

#[INPUT]
#    name    cpu
#    tag        CPU

[INPUT]
    name tail
    path /var/log/syslog
    tag demo_app

[FILTER]
    name lua
    match *
    script ../scripts/evertz_filters.lua
    call parse_filter

[OUTPUT]
    name  stdout
    match *

[OUTPUT]
    name opentelemetry
    match *
    host 10.44.48.204
    port 4318
    metrics_uri /v1/metrics
    logs_uri /v1/logs
    traces_uri /v1/traces
    log_response_payload true
    tls off
    tls.verify off
```

Following the receiver configuration of the otel collector.

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
```

I am able to send HTTP requests to the metrics and traces endpoints, namely /v1/metrics and /v1/traces. But any HTTP requests to the log endpoints, /v1/logs results in a "404 page not found". Btw, I am using Otel collector version 0.92.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated.